# Как получить сегодняшнюю дату в формате (dd.mm)?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Нужно получить дату в формате (dd.mm) Сделал так

```py
a = str(date.today())
```

Можно ли привести её к формату (dd.mm) или можно реализовать как то иначе/через другую функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, как-то так

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.today().strftime('%d.%m')
```